# Replace or delete different text in some files

Tags: regex, replace, sed

hope you understand what im asking for.
On a linux debian system

i have something like 1000 different files *.bla *.bli *.blo in different directorys.
With the following line:

```
<!--blablo--><script src="xxxx://bla.blub/bla.xxx?id=blabla" type="text/javascript"></script><!--/blablo-->

<!--blabli--><script src="xxxx://bla.blub/bla.xxx?id=blibli" type="text/javascript"></script><!--/blabli-->

<!--blublu--><script src="xxxx://bla.blub/bla.xxx?id=bloblo" type="text/javascript"></script><!--/blublu-->
```

All i want is to delete the line or replace with a space.
If anyone could be so kind and help me please.

I try with sed but i think im not smart enough to understand regex.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
for i in *.bl[aio]; do
    sed -i.bak '/--bl[a-z]bl[a-z]--/d' "$i"
done
```

Comment: <!--different--><script src="http://thisisalwaysthesame.org/different.php?id=different" type="text/javascript"></script><!--/different--> where the word different is, it is always different. Sorry but i dont know how to eplain my english is not that good :)

Comment: Unable to understand that comment.

Comment: Do you want delete all the lines that have `script src` in it?

Comment: No, then i would delete other lines with script src too. from here : <!--different--><script src="thisisalwaysthesame.org/different.php?id=different"; type="text/javascript"></script><!--/different--> <--- to there but where there word different is are different text and numbers

Comment: Then you need to provide a `search pattern` that should be sued for deleting these lines.

Comment: can this work ?  `code` find /home/aa/ -type f -exec sed -i 's/<!--[a-z0-9]--><script src="http:\//urltowebsite.com\/3EFuzF9i.php?id=[a-z0-9]" type="text\/javascript"><\/script><!--\/[a-z0-9]-->/ /g' {} \; im going crazy with this :)

Comment: It probably will but I can test it only after seeing your real input data. If you provide some real input sample in your question I can suggest something.

Answer (score 0):

I think the general ERE you need to match this:

```
<!--different--><script src="thisisalwaysthesame.org/different.php?id=different"; type="text/javascript"></script><!--/different-->
```

is this:

```
<!--[^-]+--><script src="thisisalwaysthesame[.]org/[^?]+[?]id=[^"]+"; type="text/javascript"></script><!--/[^-]+-->
```

You can't use sed since the "different" parts could always contain whichever character you choose asthe sed delimiter.

You can use `egrep -v` if you introduced a loop.

You can use awk, you just need to escape the "/"s in the RE as those are delimiters for awk, e.g. with GNU awk for inplace editing:

```
gawk -i inplace '{ print (/<!--[^-]+--><script src="thisisalwaysthesame[.]org/[^?]+[?]id=[^"]+"; type="text[/]javascript"><[/]script><!--[/][^-]+-->/ ? "" : $0) }' *.bl[aio]
```